# Software configuration files, where should I put them in Linux systems?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, configuration, bsd

I'm managing this open source project [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) and I have a decision to take about where to put all configuration files.

Currently I store [all these files](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#log-and-pid-files) under `$HOME/.pm2/`, but some user permissions can mess up with that logic.

What is the folder that is common and exists to 100% of Arch/Debian/Ubuntu/Linux/BSD/Unix... based system, to store configuration files ?

Comment: can you be more specific what is the user permission problem?

Comment: If a user, let's say www-data, doesn't have any home folder, it doesnt work. If the user root install pm2, the node user (with root access) can't access to that conf files

Comment: configuration files should be user agnostic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux/Unix, many programs usually keep config in /etc/ and use subfolder in /var/ for other files. See also on Wikipedia [File System Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)